# kernel debugger error when running my solution on window mixed reality portal

Tags: c++, uwp

I've been doing some UWP development and when i run my application on mixed reality portal it throws the below error :

```
CallContext:[\PublicAPIActivity]
onecoreuap\windows\analog\input\mirage\stubdll\holographicspace.cpp(390)\Windows.Perception.Stub.dll!0F7C1A21: (caller: 03F18204) ReturnHr(2725) tid(2eac) 80070057 The parameter is incorrect.
Exception thrown at 0x772D08B2 (KernelBase.dll) in MSIApp.exe: 0x40080201: WinRT originate error (parameters: 0x80070057, 0x00000057, 0x05AAEB64).
analog\input\mirage\publicapi\holographicspace.cpp(340)\Windows.Mirage.dll!067CA971: (caller: 0F7C1A04) ReturnHr(2728) tid(2eac) 80070057 The parameter is incorrect.
```

Anybody has any idea why this error occurs repetitively?

VS used : Vs 2017 community latest edition 15.5.6

VGA : Geforce  GTX 1060

Thank you

Comment: What's the result if you run the UWP app in the desktop directly without using mixed reality portal?  It's difficult for people helping you with only an error. Did you know in which code line the exception is thrown?

Comment: if i run application directly on hololens it works while on mixed reality portal it keeps crashing on my colleague pc it works perfectly on mixed reality portal knowing that he has same specs and same code

Comment: Could you please add  punctuation marks in your comment?

Comment: what difference does it matter? Either way all i was saying : that the code is being run on another machine with same specs works fine but on my PC it doesn't. Second, when i run the solution on my hololens it runs perfectly fine, while on mixed reality portal it keeps crashing for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems there is an issue with microsoft os and my laptop they are working on it